# How to Pull/Build parts after updating stage-packages/snapcraft.yaml file without deleting old cache, snapcraft?

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-core, snap

I was writing a snapcraft recipe and I thought am done writing it, so issued snapcraft command in base directory which resulted into a `.snap` file. I installed and run the app, which returned with some error like *lib missing etc.

I added that lib in my snapcraft.yaml file and re run the snapcraft in the base directory, which again resulted into a `.snap` file. I tested it but the changes were not included in it.

Now I don't want to clean the whole pull step of that part's cause it would be better to download that single library instead of cleaning the whole and re-download the whole cache again.

if I issue the snapcraft pull command for that specific part it says `already done`, that mean the tool not recognize the changes user made to the snapcraft file when he edited it.

Is there something I can do to get the job done or the tool needs some  more fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, you tell snapcraft how to build using a collection of parts. On each part, you have the option of using `stage-packages`, which is essentially saying "the contents of these debs and their dependencies should be included along with this part." Those packages might just be some data or libs needed at run time, or they might be something needed at build (or even pull!) time. In order to enable stage packages that are needed at pull or build time, snapcraft downloads and unpacks them in the **pull** step. This means that, if you add a new stage package to a part which has already been pulled, you must pull it again.

Granted, snapcraft should know that you added a stage package which makes the **pull** step of that part out of date. It currently doesn't (as you noted), but [it will in 2.23](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1646289).

If the stage package isn't actually needed for that part (or only needed at run time) and you really don't want to re-pull (and re-build) the part in question, you might consider splitting the new stage packages out into another, independent part:

```
extra-debs:
  plugin: nil
  stage-packages: [foo]
```